# Show offline-mode

Tags: iphone, offline-mode

What is the best way to show a user that he is in offline mode? Does Apple provide anything like a toolbar icon or what would be the best practice on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an alertview with a message notifying the user that he has no internet available.

Example:

```
  UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Network error" 
                                                message: @"Error sending 
                                                         your info to the server"  
                                                delegate: self 
                                                cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" 
                                                otherButtonTitles: nil];



  [someError show];

  [someError release];
```

I'm not sure if this is what you aim for but it is a suggestion.

Comment: Hm I am looking more like a constant information. A red bar or an icon in the tool bar so. Is this wise to do?

Comment: Then you can choose to check the reachabiliy every certain time and have an indicator that changes if the connection is broken. There is a class to do this I think itis called reachability.m and reachability.h look for it on the apple documentation. You can refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008534/how-to-verify-network-connectivity-in-objective-c

Comment: I use the reachability class already. I am more looking like a system to present the user that the internet is not reachable at the moment. Would you just misuse the networkactivity indicator for that? Looks a bit strange I think.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, why not just make a uiimageview that changes color when it is not reachable and when it is, instead of using the network activity indicator for that.

Comment: Alternatively you can use a MBProgressHUD indicator in a small format to show the user that the network is available or not. You don't have to necessarily use the network activity indicator for that. MBProgressHUD is a open source class that is very handy and very easy to use.

Comment: That loos nice! Sorry for my bad english :)